# Regular expression in awk in bash shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I'm totally a regular expression newbie and I think the problem of my code lies in the **regular expression** I use in **match** function of awk.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
line=$(sed -n '167p' models.html)
echo "line: $line"
cc=$(awk -v regex="[0-9]" 'BEGIN { match(line, regex); pattern_match=substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH+1); print pattern_match}')
echo "cc: $cc"
```

The result is:

```
line:  <td><center>0.97</center></td>
cc:
```

In fact, I want to extract the numerical value 0.97 into variable cc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

You need to pass the value of `line` into awk with `-v`:

```
awk -v line="$line" ...
```

Your regular expression only matches a single digit. To match a float, you want something like

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

No need to add 1 to the match length for the substring

```
substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH)
```

Putting it all together:

```
line='<td><center>0.97</center></td>'
echo "line: $line"
cc=$(awk -v line="$line" -v regex="[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" 'BEGIN { match(line, regex); pattern_match=substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH); print pattern_match}')
echo "cc: $cc"
```

Result:

```
line: <td><center>0.97</center></td>
cc: 0.97
```

Answer (score 2):

- You need to pass your shell variable `$line` to awk, otherwise it cannot be used within the script.
- Alternatively, you can just read the file using awk (no need to involve sed at all).
- If you want to match the `.` as well as the digits, you'll have to add that to your regular expression.

Try something like this:

```
cc=$(awk 'NR == 167 && match($0, /[0-9.]+/) { print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' models.html)
```